# Extract value from http response and store in Array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm new to the JavaScript world. I'm trying to write some code to send a request to the server and from the response it's supposed to find some specific code. With jQuery I'm able to narrow down to the class which contains these codes. Here is output of a jQuery command.

[image]

How can now I extract the the value "code=value"  and store them in an array. The output that I m looking in this case will store ["FREEDOM30", "MOVIE1000"....,"SAVE25"].

Comment: Any reason why you did it as a picture rather than just copy & paste the code?

Comment: My first choice was copy and paste , but the  content between the tags was not appearing properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for

```
var arr = new Array();

$(".coupon_code_text").each(function(){
    var tmp = $(this).attr("code");
    arr.push(tmp);
})
```

Comment: Seems alright, but I would replace `new Array()` with just `[]`, and give up on the `tmp` var altogether.

Comment: @losnir yes I can make it more clean, but it is just as pedagogical purpose ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = $('.coupon_code_text').map( function() {
              return $(this).attr('code');
          }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can extract the code property using the `.attr` function.

```
 $(".coupon_code_text").each(function(){
      var c = $(this).attr("code");
      //do something with this value
 })
```

Comment: this only would only give the attribute value for the first selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array from a function applied to every jquery element in an object using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var codes = $('.coupon_code_text').map(function(){
                return this.code;
            }).get();
```